# JAVA: Split list into smaller lists and then stream them in multiple threads

Tags: java, stream, partitioning

I have a database in which I have a table with links.

I have managed to find out that I can split a list into smaller list with the help of partitioning.
According to this article it seems that Partition class is the fastest (https://e.printstacktrace.blog/divide-a-list-to-lists-of-n-size-in-Java-8/)

After I have split them into smaller lists I would like to use these links and scrape data from them simultanously. I could have used one list and then:

```
linkList.parallelStream().forEach(link -> {
        ScrapeLink(link);});
```

And set System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "5");

But in my case I would like to split them into smaller lists and then parallelStream to another method were I use ScraperAPI to have each split of links in one session (using session_number   Reuse the same proxy by setting session_number=123 for example.)

So when I have a list like this:
final List links = Arrays.asList("link1","link2","link3","link4","link5","link6","link7");

System.out.println(Partition.ofSize(numbers, 3));

I will have [[link1, link2, link3], [link4, link5, link6], [link7]]
But how do I do then when I wants to process these small linklists in multiple threads at the same time?

My thoughts was to use Java 8 Streams. But their might be a better way?

Comment: If you had to use all these individually in seperate threads, why do you split it even in smaller lists? You could have done without splitting. Is splitting necessary? So that I can answer this question more precisely.

Comment: @abstractnature I would like to be able to split these links into different number of lists and different sizes with in the lists everytime I run my code. So basically I do not want the "new lists" looks the same every time. Otherwise I could of course made it without split them into smaller lists as you write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Default forkjoinpool (of capacity 5 as you mentioned)

and also a custom thread pool defined for your sublists.

So you need to make a runnable class like this first which you will submit later on to your "New" Threadpool

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public void LinkProcessorTask implements Runnable {
        private String link;
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do something with your link in the sublist
        }
    }
    

    public void doWork() {

      List<List<String>> subListsOfLinks = .... // partitioning function

      subListsOfLinks.parallelStream().forEach(list -> {
          ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4 //concurrency);
          for(String link: list) {
              LinkProcessorTask linkProcessorTask = new LinkProcessorTask(link);
              executorService.submit(linkProcessorTask);
              executorService.awaitTermination(//Timeout);

          }
      })
    }
```

Now its your own design decision now whether you want to make this new Threadpool a global one with fixed concurrency. or you want to invoke within your ForkJoinPool.

If you go within, `total number of threads spawned = ForkJoinPoolConcurrency * CustomThreadPoolConcurrency.`

Otherwise it will be just `ForkJoinPoolConcurrency + CustomThreadPoolConcurrency.`

Depends on your machine etc, multiple factors.

You can avoid the hefty awaitTermination method by using a `CountDownLatch`, if you want to wait for all the links of a set to complete first and then proceed ahead.

Comment: Thank you very much abstractnature for your detailed answer. I will test this tomorrow before I confirm that it will work.

Comment: Sure, dont forget to thank this answer :)

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but I have problems to understand how to use it. If I add for example:     


`
`    public void doWork() {
`        final List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
      System.out.println(Partition.ofSize(numbers, 3));
    
      List<List<String>> subListsOfLinks = Partition.ofSize(numbers, 3);
   
         .....
         .....
      .....
    }
`

How do I call doWork() and get the result to run() and do something with the link in the sublist as you wrote.

Comment: @user982455 what do you want to do with links? You call doWork() first and then it automatically does all the job for you. and if you only want to process the link, you can write that code in run() method, if you want to return something after processing, then you can pass a "result" variable in runnable only.

Comment: That was what I did I thought but saw now that I have made an mistake. I got everything running and it worked really good for my purpose. Thank you abstractnature

Answer (score 0):

Do not use streams to schedule work, it is easy to connect an input stream (via an iterator) to your workers. **It is not required** (unless the task is really fast) but, if for some reason you need to take data in chunks, you can do it directly.

The reason is that you are not processing streamed data and you will have better control over how the tasks will be executed.

For example:

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class SharedJobPool {

    @SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String... args) {

        int WORKERS = 5;
        int CHUNK = 5;

        Iterator<Integer> jobs = IntStream.range(0, 47).iterator();

        List<Thread> workers = IntStream.range(0, WORKERS).mapToObj(j -> new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                int[] chunk = new int[CHUNK];
                int size = 0;
                synchronized (jobs) {
                    while (size < CHUNK && jobs.hasNext())
                        chunk[size++] = jobs.next();
                }
                if (size == 0)
                    break;
                slowJobProccesor(j, chunk);
            }
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (Thread worker : workers)
            worker.start();

        for (Thread worker : workers)
            worker.join();

    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private static void slowJobProccesor(int j, int[] n) {
        Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1_000, 1_500));
        System.out.printf("    Thread #%d done job: %s%n", j, Arrays.stream(n).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    }
}
```

with output

```
Thread #1 done job: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
Thread #2 done job: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
Thread #4 done job: 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
Thread #3 done job: 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
Thread #0 done job: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Thread #2 done job: 30, 31, 32, 33, 34
Thread #1 done job: 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
Thread #4 done job: 35, 36, 37, 38, 39
Thread #3 done job: 40, 41, 42, 43, 44
Thread #0 done job: 45, 46, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Thank you @josejuan for your suggestions/solution. When I copy your code into a new class I can import most of but I get "errors" on range, toList and joining. The solution I get is "create method". Do you have any solution?

Comment: _"range, toList and joining"_ are static methods from `Stream` and `IntStream` (excuse me, I thought you were familiar with these methods)

Comment: (I have added the complete code, sorry for the confusion) by the way you can remove the lombok annotation and manage the exception as you need